# Running protractor E2E tests for MS Edge browser in Azure Devops CI/CD pipeline

Tags: azure, selenium-webdriver, azure-devops, protractor, webdriver-manager

I have an angular application that has e2e tests written using protractor.
I want to automate these tasks in Chrome, Firefox, & MS Edge (chromium) browsers using Azure Devops pipelines.
I am using webdriver-manager to manage the binaries.

Chrome & Firefox support headless mode & I am able to get these tests running in my Azure Devops pipeline using the *directconnect: true* option, bypassing the selenium server.

I have been struggling to automate these tests in Edge browser as webdriver-manager support for headless mode is not available.
On my local machine, I start a selenium standalone server by doing 
*webdriver-manager start --edge "pathToEdgeDriver"* & successfully run the e2e tests in Edge by specifying the seleniumAddress in my protractor.conf file.

But how do I automate this activity in Azure Devops pipelines.
I am using self hosted Azure agent with interactive mode.
I am using locally installed protractor in my project directory.

In my pipeine I have a command line task that starts the selenium server at port 4444 using the webdriver-manager start command.
However the pipeline is stuck at this task & never moves forward. Possibly its waiting for the selenium server to close before proceeding. 
I also tried starting the selenium server as a background task using a powershell script:
*Start-Process node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager start*.
This doesn't work as well

The next task in the pipeline is a command line task to execute my protractor tests.

Is there a way to achieve what I am trying to do here?

Edit: Sharing my build definition.

[Azure pipeline build definition for running e2e tests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqGNM.png)

Comment: Do you use old Edge or new Edge? Please check the blog below to see whether it helps you: https://www.sep.com/sep-blog/2020/01/29/how-to-run-protractor-e2e-tests-in-microsoft-edge-chromium/. And you may run `npm` commands in DevOps pipelines.

Comment: I use the new Edge. Yes, I have checked this blog. It was helpful & enabled me to set up Edge automation on my dev machine. Trying to set it up on DevOps pipelines.

Comment: How did you define your pipeline? Did you use `npm` commands? Could you share your build definition and entire log (set system.debug to true)?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT Have added my build definition. 
I think I found something but have not been able to try it out yet. The webdriver-manager start command should be run with the **--detach** flag. It will ensure the agent moves on to the next task. Will post an update once I try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of digging, I got this working.
The webdriver-manager needs to be started with the *--detach* flag in order to run protractor tests in visual mode (not headless) in Azure DevOps pipelines.

```
webdriver-manager start --edge "pathToEdgeDriver/msedgedriver.exe" --detach
```